# Maven archetype plugin doesn't let .resources in archetype-resources through

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, gitignore, maven-archetype

How can I make resources like `.gitignore` be part of the resulting project?

1. create archetype with `archetype-resources/.gitignore`
2. `mvn install`
3. `mvn archetype:generate`
4. resulting project doesn't contain `.gitignore`

**PS.** I'm sure it isn't there.

Comment: All the solutions here, only fix half the problem. They get the archetype built, with the `.gitignore`: but how do you generate with the `.gitignore`?

Comment: It's great how with every version the behavior has changed and one or the other tweaks have worked. Looking for a complete solution with the latest plugin versions.

Comment: A sample project to reproduce and solve the problem I am attempting can be found at [Github#fortybits/a-bit-of-archetype](https://github.com/fortybits/a-bit-of-archetype)

Answer (score 40):

The bug seems to be still present in the maven-archetype-plugin v3.0.1 .
For those who do not want to downgrade the maven-resource-plugin. I managed to establish a more or less ugly workaround.

First you rename the archetype-resources/.gitignore to

```
__gitignore__
```

then inside the `archetype-metadata.xml` add

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="gitignore">
        <defaultValue>.gitignore</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory></directory>
        <includes>
            <include>__gitignore__</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

When the archetype is generated maven will now first copy the `__gitignore__` then sees the `__[file]__` syntax and will replace it with the default value ".gitignore"

Comment: Awesome thanks!... note to everyone it's double `_`  :)

Comment: Though I could see the `__gitignore__` file copied with the latest version of archetype, yet the file is not renamed by maven.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This is the perfect workaroud

Comment: Well, I will be damned. One would expect something so simple as .gitignore appearing in the generated project would be granted, but as of 2021 it still isn't. Thank you, this actually works perfectly.

Comment: I wanted to add that for those who do not want to have a required property with a default value (i.e., so the user does not get prompted, depending on the interface they use for this), you may be able to add `#set( $gitignore = ".gitignore" )` inside one of your templates (in my case I used `pom.xml`).

Answer (score 22):

This solution for upcoming maven-resources-plugin v3.0.0 (not yet released at the time of posting this; current is still 2.7) from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-190 seems better than holding back version upgrades:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <!-- Required so that .gitignore gets included in archetypes; see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-190 -->
          <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
```

Comment: I can confirm this works using the "addDefaultExcludes".  Using the archetype 2.4 and maven-resources-plugin v.3.0.1 still has the same problem.

Comment: addDefaultExcludes works fine as described here. Finally!

Comment: The fileset entry in `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` is still needed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909897/3165190

Answer (score 13):

Add a `fileSet` entry to `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` with an empty directory tag:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory></directory>
  <includes>
    <include>.gitignore</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

This will copy the included files from `src/main/resources/archetype-resources` to the project root directory.

Answer (score 9):

Check your maven-resources-plugin version by launching the Maven build on debug (with -X option). If you use 2.7, [there is a regression where .gitignore files are silently ignored](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-190).

In this case, you will have to explicitly use 2.6 in your pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

**[ARCHETYPE/issues/ARCHETYPE-505](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARCHETYPE/issues/ARCHETYPE-505)** shows that this is thoroughly broken with current versions of the plugin and maven. No workarounds help anymore with this.

Answer (score 3):

While looking for a solution for this problem, went to the FAQ section of the maven-archetype-plugin, and, apparently, version 3.2.1 supports such case, i.e, we can now include .gitignore.
For that, config *maven-resources* and *maven-archtype-plugin*:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

*Note: I used version 3.3.0 for the maven-resources-plugin and version 3.2.1 for the maven-archetype-plugin.*

Source:
https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/faq.html#excludes

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks. Specifically, I only needed to configure maven-archetype-plugin (3.2.1).

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked perfectly for me was to use archetype post install groovy script.

Create a file `META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy` in the resources folder of your archetype project.

Add this code:

```
file = new File( request.getOutputDirectory(), request.getArtifactId()+"/.gitignore.tmpl" );
def gitIgnorefile = new File( request.getOutputDirectory(), request.getArtifactId()+"/.gitignore" );
file.renameTo(gitIgnorefile)
```

In your `archetype-metadata.xml` file include the template `.gitignore.tmpl` file.

```
        <fileSet>
            <directory/>
            <includes>
                <include>.gitignore.tmpl</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
```

I had problems with maven resource plugin hence used groovy script solution.

Comment: Question was asked long time back and maven version might be something different or there can be any other issue with it.Please try to explain your answer in better way like adding maven version or anything else that provide better insight to your answer.

Comment: The issue from the original answer is actual once again for `maven-archetype-plugin` 3.2.0 and `maven-resources-plugin` 3.2.0. The previous workaround (`<addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>`) doesn't work, but the solution with `META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy` worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Might be worth specifying that, for this to work, the `.gitignore` file in the template project must also be renamed to `.gitignore.tmpl`, matching the value of the `<include/>` property specified in this solution. Maybe obvious in hindsight, but took me a while to figure.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for downgrading `maven-resources-plugin` is to enforce `plexus-utils` version which actually has a regression:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- it's for fixing maven-resources-plugin 2.7 MRESOURCES-190 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <!-- this is last 2.x release -->
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

the bug is still in the newest  maven-archetype-plugin  2.4  and maven-resources-plugin 3.0.1.

here is the solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
 </plugin>
```

and in your generate pom.xml you should add

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: The [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37322323/859604) of vorburger is better as it does not involve using older plugins.