# .gitignore file is not copied to archetype JAR - Workarounds?

Tags: maven, gitignore, maven-archetype, maven-resources-plugin

Currently in the maven-resources-plugin there is a bug that the .gitignore file is not copied to the archetype JAR. See this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-474)

Short and simple question: are there workarounds for getting the file in the archetype?

**Edit**: setting the maven-resources-plugin version to 2.6 doesn't solve my problem (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981060/maven-archetype-plugin-doesnt-let-resources-in-archetype-resources-through))

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven archetype plugin doesn't let .resources in archetype-resources through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981060/maven-archetype-plugin-doesnt-let-resources-in-archetype-resources-through)

Comment: Did you examine these options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981060/maven-archetype-plugin-doesnt-let-resources-in-archetype-resources-through ?

Comment: Yes looks like the same problem, but didn't helped

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The bug is now fixed in the maven-resources-plugin.

To include the .gitignore file, the maven-resources-plugin plugin should be set explicitly in the archetype `pom.xml` file with the configuration value `addDefaultExcludes` set to `false`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: At the moment I am writing this message, this solution works.
Note : specifying version is necessary. If not specifying <version>3.0.2</version>, it does not work

Comment: Stopped working for me with `3.0.2` and Maven `3.5.4`... I wonder if anybody else is affected...

Comment: Just as reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-190

Comment: see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARCHETYPE/issues/ARCHETYPE-505, currently nothing will help

Answer (score 1):

As @amanteaux says, adding `addDefaultExcludes` with `false` ensures that the maven-resources-plugin copies the `.gitignore` file to `target/classes`, however, maven-jar-plugin (> 2.4) won't copy `.gitignore` to the resulting jar. See [this stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514758/maven-jar-plugin-does-not-include-gitignore-file#comment97762035_55522970) for more information. So one workaround would be, in addition to the flag above for maven-resources-plugin, rollback maven-jar-plugin to 2.4.