# maven-jar-plugin does not include .gitignore file

Tags: maven, gitignore, maven-jar-plugin

I try to package an application into a jar file with maven. Somehow all files except `.gitignore` files are added to the jar.

Why is this file skipped and how can I disable this?

Even if I try to include it like below the include is ignored and the jar file remains empty.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/.gitignore</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- maven-jar-plugin version: 3.1.0
- maven version: 3.5.2

Comment: Why do you want to include .gitignore into a jar? It is useless to java, and within a jar it is useless to git.

Comment: The jar is used as a container to package a development ready sample application in an already existing workflow.

Comment: From my point of view you should better use a zip archive for this.

Comment: But I guess that your .gitignore is also not found in the target directory - right? This means you need to copy it to there via the resource plugin - otherwise the jar plugin can't find it.

Comment: I have told the resource plugin to copy the .gitignore file via `addDefaultExcludes` to target. This is working. But the maven-jar-plugin still ignores it.

Comment: Please add some information about your project structure and the result that you expect.

Comment: Might be that you must copy the .gitignore into target/classes so that the jar plugin can catch it.

Comment: @ochs.tobi When you say "_to target_" do you mean `target/classes`? Since that's the [JAR plugin's default `<classesDirectory>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) "_containing the classes and resource files that should be packaged into the JAR_".

Comment: My sources are copied to `target/classes`. The .gitignore file is also there.

Comment: Every other file can be added with the above code snippet like: `.tfignore` or others only .gitignore seems impossible to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this with a `src/main/resources/.gitignore` and it worked with the default `maven-jar-plugin:2.4`, i.e. `.gitignore` was packaged into the JAR.

Then I used the `maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0` you mention and it did *not* work, as you describe.

It turned out that it doesn't work from v2.5 onwards.

Comment: That's the same that I discovered. So maybe there is no chance to do this with maven-jar-plugin >= 3

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with a `.metadata` folder in the `target/classes` folder. The `.metadata` folder is not included in the jar archive.
For me, it is not working with `maven-jar-plugin:2.4` and upper. With version 2.3 it is working.

I submitted this issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-265

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is using a jar file example projects is astonishing. I would never expect to have example projects within a `.jar` file. The intention of a jar files is something different. I would suggest to use something more appropriate like `.zip` or `.tar.gz` etc. (This can be achieved with the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html)) This will prevent accidental not intended use.

Apart from the whole problem is based on the definition of resources which are usually copied from `src/main/resources` to the `target/classes` directory. This is done by the `maven-resources-plugin`.

The [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) plugin has some kind of configuration which excludes some [files which are usually not copied](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) which contains `.gitignore`. So this means just putting a `.gitignore` file into `src/main/resources` will not produce the expected result nor using `<includes>..</includes>` configuration will not help here as well.

This means you need to change the default configuration of maven-resources-plugin via `pluginManagement` section like the following:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Than the `.gitignore` file will be copied and should be packaged into the resulting jar file (Which I would not recommend to do.)

Comment: That's right. I already managed to copy the files with the resources plugin to `target/classes`. But the `maven-jar-plugin` > 2.4 also skips `.gitignore` files.